# Entity Framework: Lazyloading appears to be off despite explicitly turning it on?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

It would appear that my model first EF set up is not lazy loading related table records despite explicitly turning it on (which I understand I should not have to do since it's model first).

Code follows:

```
Using db As New Entity()

    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = True

    Dim objectList as List(Of tableName) = _
        db.tableName.Include("relatedTableName") _
        .Where(Function(x) x.col1 = someValue) _
        .OrderBy(Function(x) x.col2).ThenBy(Function(x) x.col3).ToList()

    int testVal = 0

    For Each item As tableName In objectList
        testValue = item.relatedTableName.idColumn
    Next
End Using
```

I get a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error on this line:

```
testValue = item.relatedTableName.idColumn
```

In fact, `item.relatedTableName` doesn't have a value either. I have verified that I should be getting records back by writing an inner join statement in SQL.

What's going on here?

Comment: `Include` is not lazy but *eager* loading. This isn't related to lazy loading on/off.

Comment: I know that and that was current state of code at time of question and doesn't turn off lazy loading and didn't help or make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the navigation property from a nullable field to the related table when there is more than 1 foreign key between the two tables will do this if you use the wrong navigation property.

That is to say that navigation properties `relatedTableName` and `relatedtableName1` need to be used according to the data you want. If the first one points to a nullable street address column and the second one points to a non-nullable zip code column, point to the right one and expect a possible null object and null column.